# Changing the look of fields in rails using css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, html, input

On a standard html page I know how to change the look of an input, but on rails my inputs are structured like

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br/>
  <span style="color:red;font-weight: normal; font-size:11px; "><%= errors_for(:name, @user) %> </span>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>      
</div>
```

And they display in a browser like normal fields. How can I use css to make it look like the search bar on the top of this page http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/tutorials/ (slightly rounded edges, 1px #999 stroke, larger size) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to apply CSS to the actual `<input>`

```css
.field input {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gqPx/)